# Rasterize solid 3D-building blocks with QGIS

Tags: qgis, rasterization

Stockholm city provides 3D building blocks as open vector data. I want to rasterize these solid cubes to be able to perform a multi criteria analysis. But no matter which rasterize-command I try in QGIS, the output .tiff-file turns black!? The Z-column in my vector file is called "Z".

Any ideas?

[image]

This is how the attribute data for the 3D blocks looks like:
[image]

Comment: Please explain how you are performing the rasterize command process.

Comment: I've tried v.to.rast.value and v.to.rast.attribute, also Raster > Conversion > Rasterize (Vector to Raster) (setting the attribute field to Z and "Keep existing raster size and resolution) and SAGA > Rasterize. I must be doing something terrible wrong since the output is totally black.

Comment: Looking at the histogram on my rasterized file shows me nothing, it's like all the rasterize commands can't handle the solid 3D blocks?

Comment: Do you a have a link to the data?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwFHJFrNX33hX2ZEZnZmdG5hUUk

Comment: Basically I want to write the z-values from that vector-file to a raster, so that each pixel has a elevation value. Could that be possible?

Comment: There is no reason why it shouldn't be possible. The link to the data just has the shp. Do you have the associated files, such as the .shx, .dbf, .prj?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwFHJFrNX33hZGFoT2xiVXZSbGs